# Reflection can't find constructor

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have that class:

```
public class DNDRunner {
    private NotificationManager mNoMan;

    public DNDRunner(Context context) {
        mNoMan = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public void run(String param) {
        mNoMan.setZenMode(Integer.parseInt(param), null, "DNDRunner");
    }
}
```

And i call run method by reflection using:

```
try {
    Class mRunner = Class.forName(runner);
    Constructor constructor = mRunner.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class});
    Object object = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{mContext});
    Method run = mRunner.getMethod("run", new Class[]{String.class});
    run.invoke(object, new Object[]{value});
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Runner", e);
}
```

but i get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
```

what i'm doing wrong? the constructor is obviously there

**UPDATE:**

Testing with:

```
private void executeRunner() {
    try {
        Class mRunner = Class.forName(runner);
        Constructor<?> constructor = mRunner.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Is public constructor? " + Modifier.isPublic(constructor.getModifiers()));
        Object object = constructor.newInstance(mContext);
        Method run = mRunner.getDeclaredMethod("run", String.class);
        run.invoke(object, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Runner", e);
    }
}
```

But i get the same error:

```
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction: Runner
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2166)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnilib.actions.OmniAction.executeRunner(OmniAction.java:148)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnilib.actions.OmniAction.execute(OmniAction.java:89)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnibrain.EventService.execOmniActions(EventService.java:302)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnibrain.EventService.execOnConnectActions(EventService.java:257)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnibrain.EventService.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at org.omnirom.omnibrain.EventService$2.onReceive(EventService.java:189)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52497(LoadedApk.java:1313)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.$m$7(Unknown Source:4)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.run(Unknown Source:39)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
06-25 20:24:44.703  2420  2420 E OmniAction:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-25 20:24:44.705  1692  1697 I zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=507KB, data=308KB
```

Weird .... :(

I can't understand how it can find the class but it can't read the constructor.

I'm cleaning all the references to previous code before build again:

```
find out/ -name *OmniBrain* -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: is this a top-level class? or a class inside other class?

Comment: top-level class

Comment: can you maybe post more code then? make sure that you are getting right class too, maybe there is some similar one.

Comment: all the related code is here:

https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/q/status:open++branch:android-8.1+topic:action_runners

Comment: that are 2 different modules? I think that when you are testing it is still using old code where you didn't have public constructor in `DNDRunner` - if you are unable to check that in some normal way - you can check this by using `getDeclaredConstructor` it should be able to get that constructor and you can print if it is public to console `Modifier.isPublic(constructor.getModifiers())`
https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/c/android_packages_apps_OmniBrain/+/31227/2..1/src/org/omnirom/omnibrain/runners/DNDRunner.java

Comment: One is a static library, the other is an apk . I will test your suggestion, thanks

Comment: you are going to laugh ... proguard is erasing the unused methods, I kept the classes in my proguard configuration but forget the methods ... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to laugh ... proguard is erasing the unused methods, I kept the classes in my proguard configuration but forget the methods ... LOL

https://gerrit.omnirom.org/c/android_packages_apps_OmniBrain/+/31227/3/proguard.flags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = mRunner.getConstructor(Context.class); 
Object object = constructor.newInstance(this)
```